# Merging same form questions into one columns

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, group-by, merge, google-forms

I have a form with 20 sections, all of them with the same questions aside the first one. I'm looking for a way to organize the answers under the same "header" grouped by the first answer.

first 4 questions are standard for every user (col A,B,C and D), and from then on, Col E = "what article do you need?", Col F = "How many?", Col G = Yes/ No answer , where if yes, it loops around to Col H = "what article do you need?", Col I = " How many?, Col J = Yes/No, etc...

I'm looking for a way for all potential answers to grouped by the first 4 answers, in such way that Cols = "what article do you need?" are all in the same column and Cols = "How many?" are respectively organized by "what article do you need?" answer in another column.

Here is the drive

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zdHF3Ea1_b-HxNJ7kbujHNWXKNGGTgU8MBA6mogJyN8/edit#gid=346967285

Sheet 2 is the intended result, in a way that answer automatically get sorted out.

Hope I managed to be clear.
Is this possible?

Comment: the shared sheet has *restricted* access

Comment: Your question must stand alone. Please do not expect that users can/should/will open your spreadsheet to better understand your spreadsheet, data or the expected result. ALL the relevant information should be included _in_ your question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(rep_,'Form Responses 1'!A2:D, grp_,'Form Responses 1'!E2:BL, size_,3,
     Σ,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,{rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}))),
     choosecols(sort(filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(grp_))<>""),1,1),sequence(6)))
```

[image]

Comment: You good sir, are a God's gift! thank you ever so much!